# show posts under custom post type with same autj

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, customization

there are several authors on my site. I have a post type called jobs and I have a few articles where the author of the articles and post type jobs are the same, how can I show the articles of each author under their post type jobs page?
Each author has his own page in Jobs.
I am a newbie, if you can explain something like this to me, thank you
this code get the currect author id but how show the posts under jobs?

```
$user_id = get_post_field( 'post_author', $post_id );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can you this code to show posts based on user:

```
$args = array(
'author'        =>  $user_id,
'orderby'       =>  'post_date',
'order'         =>  'ASC',
'posts_per_page' => 1
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: thank's for reply;
that's work but most add echo to show post `while ( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post(); echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>'; }`

Comment: You can use the_title() and the_content() for this and if user data stored in post_meta then you need to echo.